# how to select the last inserted record in table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Hello I am  trying to create a relatively simple trigger that when an employee is inserted to my table certified (which is where my many-to-many relationship is located, each employee can be certified for more than one jobs and each job can be done by more than one employees)
I would like the trigger to check if including the inserted record the employee is now certified in more than 3 jobs to give him a 10% raise.
This is what I tried first but then i realized that what i have done affects the whole table:

```
create trigger raise 
on certified
after insert 
as
begin
update employees set salary = salary + (salary*0.1)
where (select count(job_id) from certified where empid = (select empid from 
inserted) group by empid)>3
end
```

My question is how is it possible to get only the last inserted record?

Comment: Not an answer, but you may need another procedure to remove the raise should the employee no long be certified for 3 or more jobs.

Comment: I believe you are looking for an output statement.

Comment: So for every new certification when they have at least three they will receive an additional 10% raise? If a given employee has 11 certifications they would receive 8 10% salary increases which would more than double their salary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last inserted record is inside "inserted" table.

I think this update below will solve the problem. Remember that you should only increase the salary in the first time the certified jobs increase above 3. You shoudn't increase the salary for the 5th or 6th certified job.

```
update employees set salary=salary + (salary*0.1)
where empid in
(select empid from certified where empid in
  (select empid from inserted) and (select count(job_id)
    from certified b
    where b.empid=certified.empid)=3+ 
        (select count(job_id) from inserted
            where inserted.empid=certified.empid)
)
```

Remember to also build a delete trigger. However, as a developer, I wouldn't build this business rule in triggers.